# Array of days in a month and get the value from each position

Tags: android, datetime

Here is my data structure which is all the days in february. How can i make the day today to be equal from the data for example today is 22 = 21. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QckQ.png)

Here is my current code

```
 SimpleDateFormat day = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                int daysInMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


                ArrayList<String> allDays = new ArrayList<>();
                for(int i = 0; i < daysInMonth; i++){

                    allDays.add(day.format(calendar.getTime()));


                }
```

Comment: You never set `daysInMonth` in `Calender` for first time.

Comment: add "Na" at first index

Comment: @ADM What I didn't set??

Comment: I can not figure out what you trying to do with this code . Please Edit your question and add what you want to achieve .

Comment: @ADM check the image on my post

Comment: Basically, you need all day of the month in a list right?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this code,

```html
SimpleDateFormat day = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        List<String> allDays = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); i++){
            allDays.add(i, String.valueOf(i+1));
        }
```

[image: this will be your allDays list.]

Comment: How can I equal the date today from the array? alldays.get(day today)

Comment: allDays.get(Integer.parseInt(day.format(calendar.getTime()

Comment: you can get today's date using this : allDays.get(Integer.parseInt(day.format(calendar.getTime()-1));

Comment: - cannot be applied to date.

Comment: try this -         String todayDate = allDays.get(Integer.parseInt(day.format(calendar.getTime())));

Comment: Yup but i need to -1 to equal it from the data structure. Should i change this to allDays.add(i, String.valueOf(i - 1));

Comment: yes, you can but you will get a date "-1 " at 0 position of the list.

Comment: what you exactly want to do with this list?

Comment: I want to get the value from the data structure depends on the day of the month. So if its 1st day of the month it's 0

Comment: ok, you can try this - allDays.add(i, String.valueOf(i - 1));

Comment: Yup i tried setting a String to = "01/02/2019" and parse it and got a 0 value so that's correct thanks for your help